# How to Hide the phone ringing screen when my Application is running

Tags: android, notifications, phone-call

How to hide phone ringing screen when i am using my application without notifying the caller i.e. without unanswered the call?

**I mean when call comes in between when i was using my application call screen must hide and i can use my application without interruption and call can b shown on notification.**

Please tell is there any way.

This is possible please check the link below:
http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2011/05/callbackgrounder-1024x606.jpg

Comment: no way... in android calling thread has highest priority. So, u cant do what u desire. As i think.

Comment: any other way to use my app without interruption...

Comment: I was thinking to use Broadcastrecivers to open activity from my app when phone rings. will it work?

Comment: yeah you can use ACTION_ANSWER with an intent to open your activity whenever your phone got an incoming call

Comment: Please check this link: http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2011/05/callbackgrounder-1024x606.jpg

Comment: well... it seems , it possible by giving user a option to keep the calling activity in background.